# Deeplinking from posted FB feed links doesn't work anymore

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, deep-linking

i have an app made with unity, where users can post a link from the app to their facebook feed. When another user clicks on this link, the app opens if installed, or the app store opens if not installed. Well, that worked great with the SDK 6.0 so i'm pretty sure i have a correct setup.

I have updated the SDK to 6.2.1 now this feature doesn't work for newly created feed links!
Instead when clicking on a newly created feed link with the updated SDK, the website opens up. 
But all other feed links created with the older SDK 6.0 still works fine?!

So i'm guessing something is wrong when posting a new FB.Feed with the new SDK.
Did i miss something with the new sdk?

Any help would be very appreciated!